# MBProgressHUD resize works in version 0.4, fails in version 0.5

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

I'm presenting an MBProgressHUD over a table with a back button in the navigation bar while requesting data from a remote web service.

By default the HUD covers the entire window, preventing taps from reaching the underlying UI elements. I want to change this so the navigation bar DOES receive taps, so a tap on the back button can cancel the request and dismiss the HUD.

In MBProgressHUD 0.4 I do this by changing the 'initWithView:' method:

```
#if 1
    // SPC 2012-02-25 don't cover navigation bar (so user can cancel)
    CGRect _bounds = view.bounds;
    _bounds.origin.y += 64.0;
    _bounds.size.height -= 64.0;
    id me = [self initWithFrame:_bounds];
#else
    id me = [self initWithFrame:view.bounds];
#endif
```

and this works as expected.

I make the same change in MBProgressHUD 0.5:

```
#if 1
    // SPC 2013-03-15 don't cover navigation bar (so user can cancel)
    CGRect _bounds = view.bounds;
    _bounds.origin.y    += 64.0;
    _bounds.size.height -= 64.0;
    return [self initWithFrame:_bounds];
#else
    return [self initWithFrame:view.bounds];
#endif
```

but the HUD still covers the entire window.

I've stepped through the code in both versions, and all it does after this modified code is to call 'addSubview:' to add the newly-created HUD to what becomes its parent view.

Any ideas on why it's failing in 0.5, and what I might do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set hud `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` and hud will pass touch event to its underlying views.